# complexity on a annidate for cycle

Tags: for-loop, complexity-theory

i would like to know if the solution for the complexity of that code is correct:

```
for (j = 2^N; j>1; j = j/2) {
              h = h * 2;
          for (i =1; i < j; i = i*2)
             for (k=2; k<log N; k++)
                cont ++;
}
```

According me the last cycle have complexity log n

The first cycle have complexity n

The second cycle have complexity log n

So the total complexity is n log n

Best Regards

Comment: `h` here is useless, right?

Answer (score 0):

You have three loops here:

1. First is linear in N (logarithmic in 2^N)
2. Second is linear in N (logarithmic in 2^N)
3. Third is logarithmic in N

So the whole code looks rather as `O(N^2 log N)`

Comment: But excuse me, the first and second loop are dipendent and if they are dipendent at university told me that i don't have to do the product between them but find the max so, in that case N and the final result is N * logn and not N^2 * logn
it's not possible that the second loop have a complexity of N^2?